# Geometry problem: finding coordinates on outer circle using extrusion from centre through point of inner circle

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

My problem involves an inner circle (centre $I$) with a displaced placement within an outer circle (centre $O$). I have a point placed somewhere on the circumference of the inner circle ($P$). I wish to extrude from point $P$ orthogonally until it reaches and intersects the outer circle at position $Q$, **so I need to calculate the position of $Q$.**

The radius of the outer circle ($r_1$), inner circle ($r_2$) and displacement of inner circle ($r_3$) are known.

[image: circle within a circle image description]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Some background:**

I actually need to do this for multiple points on the inner circle ($P_1$, $P_2$ etc, but I have all these coordinates). What I have so far:

$x_Q = x_I + \frac{(x_P - x_I) \cdot r_1}{\sqrt{(x_P - x_I)^2 + (y_P - y_I)^2}}$

$y_Q = x_I + \frac{(y_P - y_I) \cdot r_1}{\sqrt{(x_P - x_I)^2 + (y_P - y_I)^2}}$

which gives me something like this, but the magnitude is wrong:

[image: lines extruded orthogonally from origin of inner circle]

I then tried adding the original displacement of the inner circle,

$x_Q = x_I + \frac{(x_P - x_I) \cdot r_1}{\sqrt{(x_P - x_I)^2 + (y_P - y_I)^2}} + r_3$

$y_Q = x_I + \frac{(y_P - y_I) \cdot r_1}{\sqrt{(x_P - x_I)^2 + (y_P - y_I)^2}}$

but now the lines aren't orthogonal:

[image: lines extruded from inner circle to intersect with outer circle]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Suggest use "center" rather than "origin" for your inner and outer circles [in the diagrams your origins are actually centers.]

Comment: Should the required lines be curved so that they are orthogonal to both circles centered at O and I?

Comment: No, one straight line that is orthogonal from the centre of I through point P that is on the circumference of I and ends at Q that is on the circumference of O

Comment: This question is not about linear algebra. Please, choose the tags carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $O,I,P$ be the outer and inner circle centers, and the point on the inner cirle. Let $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the Euclidean distance, and $t$ a parameter to be found. Set up the equation $$d(O,\ I+t(P-I))=r$$ where $r$ is the radius of the larger "outer" circle. This may be solved for $t$, make things easier by squaring the sides first. For your purpose you only want solution with $t>0.$ Once you have a number for $t$ you can fill it in to $I+t(P-I)$ to get the desired point on the outer circle.

**Added**
Another description: With $P,I,O$ as the points viewed as vectors, a dot product version gives the quadratic equation
$$at^2+bt+c=0, \\ a=(P-I)\cdot (P-I),\\ 
b=2(I-O)\cdot(P-I) \\ c=(I-O) \cdot (I-O) - r^2$$

Comment: Thanks for this. If squaring, then I would need to expand and solve the resulting quadratic equation, I assume?

Comment: Try a special case with numbers for everything known.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure what you meant with a special case. I expanded the equation and used the quadratic formula to solve for t:
$(x_O-x_I)^2 - 2t(x_O-x_I)(x_P-x_I) + t^2(x_P-x_I)^2 + (y_O-y_I)^2 - 2t(y_O-y_I)(y_P-y_I) + t^2(y_P-y_I)^2 = r^2$.

Let 
$a =  (x_O-x_I)^2 + (y_O-y_I)^2 - r^2$

$b = 2((x_O-x_I)(x_P-x_I)+(y_O-y_I)(y_P-y_I))$
giving:
$a + t^2((x_P-x_I)^2 + (y_P-y_I)^2) + bt = 0$
Then solve for t using the quadratic formula:
$t = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4a}}{2((x_P - x_I)^2 + (y_P - y_I)^2)}$

But am not getting what I expect. is this the direction you expected?
Many thanks

Comment: Your version seems far off. On the left side of a single equation [with r^2 on right side] should be *six* terms, three involving products of differences of subscripted x's and three more similar ones involving products of differences of subscripted y's. Of these six terms, two contain $t$ and two contain $t^2.$ After that of course you may want to set $a,b$ to certain things before passing to use of quadratic equation, but I do not follow what you did there.

Comment: I believe this is what I have done. Maybe it is the formatting that is causing issue here. I have 6 terms, three with subscripted x's and three with subscripted y's, two terms with t and two with t^2: 

$(x_O−x_I)^2−2t(x_O−x_I)(x_P−x_I)+t^2(x_P−x_I)^2+(y_O−y_I)^2−2t(y_O−y_I)(y_P−y_I)+t^2(y_P−y_I)^2 = r^2$

Comment: Then I let:
$a = (x_O-x_I)^2 + (y_O-y_I)^2 - r^2$

And I let:
$b = 2((x_O-x_I)(x_P-x_I) + (y_O-y_I)(y_P-y_I)$.

This then gives me: $a+t^2((x_P−x_I)^2+(y_P−y_I)^2)+bt=0$

Comment: Then I use the quadratic formula to solve for t. If this is the correct methodology that you mean, I will continue working on it. Right now I am experiencing negative determinants from some values of $x_P$ and $y_P$ that are causing issues, but I can continue troubleshooting

Comment: I will append a version involving dot products of vectors.

Comment: I see from your later comments you have done the right steps. The more I consider it, things might be easier in a few steps. 1) get the equation of the line through I and P, 2) write the standard equation for the large circle. 3) use algebra to find the two intersections between the line and the big circle. 4) decide which of the two points you want, since P should be between I and the intersection with the big circle.

Comment: mm that is quite an elegant way of solving the problem... actually, so long as the number of points on the inner circle is even, I can just take both intersections between that line and the outer circle. I will give this a try. Thank you again for your efforts! :)

Comment: @YoshuaMoore I think you mean not only even number of points on inner circle but also the points come in antipodal pairs.

Comment: Yes exactly, that would be a more accurate/general description. (In my case, I place the points equally spaced on the inner circle, so an even number would always be antipodal). I will give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: At this point I myself would throw it all into a computer algebra system...

Comment: I got it working using what you suggested, by finding the intersection to the circle from the line between I and P. Thank you very much for your time. You saved me a lot of headache (I am a chemist, not a mathematician, so this problem would have been extremely challenging for me to solve alone). Wish you a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you presumably know the coordinates of $I$ and $O$ in your figure.
Then, knowing the coordinates of $P$, you can compute the angle
$\angle OIP$ and its sine, $\sin(\angle OIP)$.

Specifically, let $u$ be the vector from $I$ to $O$ and let $u$ be the vector from $I$ to $P$. Then

\begin{align}
\cos(\angle OIP) &= \frac{u \cdot v}{\lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert}, \\
\sin(\angle OIP) &= \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(\angle OIP)}, \\
\angle OIP &= \arccos(\cos(\angle OIP)).
\end{align}

Note that this always gives an angle between zero and $\pi$ radians,
so you'll also need to keep track of which "side" of the line $IO$ the point $P$ is on so you can project it to the correct point on the outer circle and not the mirror-image point across line $IO.$

Now apply the law of sines and the fact that $\angle OIP = \angle OIQ$
in the triangle $\triangle OIQ$:

$$ \frac{\sin(\angle OIP)}{\angle OIP} = \frac{\sin(\angle IQO)}{\angle IQO}. $$

Therefore
$$
\angle IQO = \frac{\sin(\angle IQO)}{\sin(\angle OIP)}\angle OIP.
$$

Then
$$ \angle IOQ = \pi - \angle OIP - \angle IQO. $$

From $\angle IOQ$ and the radius $r_1$ you can project $Q$ from $O$,
just taking care to avoid the mirror-image location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I looked at this. I have the angles $OIP$ but I am not sure how I am supposed to get $sin(IQO)$ from the law of sines? as I still don't have the angle $IQO$

Answer (score 0):

We use polar coordinates. We can ignore point P because it anyhow lies on radius IQ and that PQ is always perpendicular to inner circle centered at I. No need even to label it.

$$ IQ=r, ~~ IO =d, \text{ labeled in place of }r_3; $$

[image]

By Cosine Rule on triangle  $I Q_1 O$ we have

$$r_1^2=r^2+d^2-2rd \cos(\pi-\theta),$$

$$ r^2+2rd \cos \theta +(d^2-r_1^2) =0 ~;$$

Solutions of the quadratic equation

$$ r_{1,2}=d\cos \theta\pm \sqrt { r_1^2 - (d \sin \theta)^2)} $$

The (the extended ) radius vector intersects the outer circle at *two* points $Q_1,Q_2$ centered at $I$ as shown above.

$$ (x_{Q_1},y_{Q_1})= r_1( \cos\theta, \sin\theta); (x_{Q_2},y_{Q_2})= r_2( \cos\theta, \sin\theta).~$$

EDIT

A polar plot and `Mathematica` code is also attached:

[image]

Slight label change. Red circle radii $\rho_{1,2}$ at $ Q_{1,2}$ is eccentric to circle of radius $\rho_2$ centered at I.